# Gauss-Legendre three point rule

Tags: integration, proof-verification, numerical-methods

> Use the change of variables $$x=\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}t,$$ to show that $$\int^b_a f(x) \ dx = \frac{b-a}{2} \int^1_{-1} f\left( \frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{b-a}{2}t \right) \ dt.\tag{1}$$Hence obtain the Gauss 3 point rule for the interval $[ a, b ]$: $$\int^b_a f(x) dx \approx \frac{b-a}{18} \left( 5f \left( \frac{a+b}{2}- \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \frac{b-a}{2} \right) + 8 f\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)+ 5f \left( \frac{a+b}{2}  + \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \frac{b-a}{2}\right)  \right).\tag{2}$$

**Attempt:**

Using the change of variable $x=\frac{a+b}{2}+ \frac{b-a}{2}t,$ we will have $dx=\frac{b-a}{2}dt.$ But how can I justify the change of integration limits to $[-1, 1]$? This is what we would have:

$$\int^1_{-1} f\left( \frac{a+b}{2} + \frac{b-a}{2}t \right) \ dt = f(b-a)$$

Furthermore, the Gauss-Legendre three point rule for the interval $[-1,1]$ is: $$\int^1_{-1} g(t)dt \approx \frac{5}{9}g \left(-\sqrt{3/5} \right) + \frac{8}{9}g(0)+\frac{5}{9}g\left(\sqrt{3/5} \right).\tag{3}$$

I was told we will need to use this result in order to arrive at equation **(2)**. So, how can I use **(1)** and **(3)** to arrive at **(2)**?

Comment: Replace $t$ by $1$ and $-1$ and see what value of $x$ you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To get the new limits of integration, use that $\displaystyle t=\frac{2x-(a+b)}{b-a}$.

To get the formula for the interval $[a,b]$, use the formula for the interval $[-1,1]$ with $g(t)=f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}t\right)$

Comment: But shouldn't I instead substitute $g(t)= \frac{b-a}{2} f \left( \frac{a+b}{2}+ \frac{b-a}{2}t \right)$ instead? Because if I substitute $g(t)= f \left( \frac{a+b}{2}+ \frac{b-a}{2}t \right)$ I get:$$\frac{1}{9} \left( 5f(\frac{a+b}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \frac{b-a}{2})+8 f (\frac{a+b}{2})+5f(\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}) \right).$$This is not correct, because we need a $(b-a)/2$ factor to get to equation **(2)**. How do we justify this?

Comment: The factor of $\frac{b-a}{2}$ comes from the expression for dx.

Comment: But the only thing that we are substituting into equation **(3)** is $g(t)=f\left(  \frac{a+b}{2}+ \frac{b-a}{2}t  \right).$ Why would we multiply **(3)** by the expression for $dx$?

Comment: Making the suggested change of variable gives Equation (1), which has the factor of $\frac{b-a}{2}$ in front (since $dx=\frac{b-a}{2}dt$).