# Numerical integration in Matlab (Gaussian 3 point quadrature)

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab

> Write a Matlab function that applies the Gauss three point rule to N sub-intervals of $[a, b].$ The input parameters should be the name of the function being integrated, $a, b,$ and $N$.

**Attempt:**

For $\int^b_a f(x) dx$ the [Gaussian 3 point quadrature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794159/gauss-legendre-three-point-rule/) is given by:

$$\frac{b-a}{18} \left( 5f \left( \frac{a+b}{2}- \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \frac{b-a}{2} \right) +8f \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) + 5 f \left(  \frac{a+b}{2}+ \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \frac{b-a}{2} \right)  \right).$$

Here is my Matlab code that uses this equation to approximate $\int^b_a f(x) dx$:

```
function t = gauss3(func,a,b)
j=(((a+b)/2)-sqrt(3/5)*((b-a)/2));
k=((a+b)/2);
l=(((a+b)/2)+sqrt(3/5)*((b-a)/2));
t=((b-a)/18)*(5*feval(func,j) + 8*feval(func,k) + 5*feval(func,l))

function y=f(x)
y=exp(-x^2);
> t = gauss3(@f,0,1)
```

So how can I modify this code to take into account the sub-intervals $N$? The function should start as `function t = gauss3(func,a,b,N)`.

**P.S.** In the code above I am trying to approximate the integral $\int^1_0 e^{-x^2} \ dx,$ using the Gaussian three point rule with error $<10^{-10}.$

**Edit:**

```
function y = gaussq(func,a,b,N);

h = (b-a)/N;
y = 0;
for i = 1:N,
    y = y+gauss3(func,a+(i-1)*h,a+i*h);
end
% y0 = 100;
% for N = logspace(0,6,7),
%     y1 = gaussq(@f,a,b,N);
%     err = abs((y1-y0)/y0);
%     if err < 1.0e-10,
%         break;
%     end
%     y0 = y1;
% end
```

Where:

```
function y=f(x)
y=exp(-x^2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't modify the code except to suppress output on the last line of gauss3.m. All you need is a function that chops up $[a,b]$ into $N$ subintervals and invokes gauss3.m $N$ times and adds up the results:

```
% gaussq.m

function y = gaussq(func,a,b,N);

h = (b-a)/N;
y = 0;
for i = 1:N,
    y = y+gauss3(func,a+(i-1)*h,a+i*h);
end
```

Then you want a script that invokes the above for various values of $N$ and compares results until it's satisfied that the error criterion is met:

```
% testg.m

a = 0;
b = 1;
y0 = 100;
for N = logspace(0,6,7),
    y1 = gaussq(@f,a,b,N);
    err = abs((y1-y0)/y0);
    if err < 1.0e-10,
        break;
    end
    y0 = y1;
end
fprintf('Integral = %17.15f, intervals = %d, error = %e\n',y1,N,err);
```

Hopefully after you analyze the above example to see how it operates you will be able to write your own, much better, code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I have just a few more questions. In your 2nd code why did you use `N = logspace(0,6,7)`? When I select e.g. $N=21$ I get ~500 outputs! 
I'm trying to work out how big $N$ has to be in order to get an approximation to $I$ with error $<10^{-10}.$ For Simpson's rule the error is $\approx Ch^4$, so for integral $I=\int^1_0 e^{-x^2}$ I already worked out $C$ to be $0.0081.$ For 3 point Gauss the error is $Ch^6$, so $N$ will be $20.79 \approx 21$. But when I run your code without the error script, the output after 21 steps is 0.045 instead of 0.74..., Why?

Comment: You can get the value of $C$ for the Gauss $3$-point rule by computing $$\int_{-1}^1\left(P_3(x)\right)^2dx$$ where $P_3(x)=\frac12(5x^3-3x)$ is the Legendre polynomial of order $3$. The normalization of the Legendre polynomials tells you that the integral is $\frac2{2\cdot3+2}=\frac27$,but Gauss says $0$. From that you get $C$. That formula for Gauss integration error is generally a crappy upper bound and some integrals perform much better, like sines, cosines, and exponentials. $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\text{erf}(1)=0.746824132812427$. Post your code. Works for me. Need $N=10$.

Comment: Thank you. I was analyzing the code you've posted. I have copied that into my post above. For `y = gaussq(@f,0,1,10);` I get $t=0.04058...$ instead of $0.7468145841$. Why is that? And when I uncomment the error section I get the right solution but with around ~500 iterations instead of 10. And then I get the error: `Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached`. What is wrong here?

Comment: OK, now I see where you are getting $t=0.04058$ from: those are the values of the integrals over the subintervals being printed out by gauss3.m. I told you to suppress its output and you do that by putting a semicolon at the end of the last line, the one the sets the value of $t$. Do that one thing and report back on your results. For me gaussq(@f,0,1,6) prints out $0.746824132779392$.

Comment: Oops, thank you very much, that solved the problem. I am wondering if it is possible to work out $C$ and therefore $N$ for a certain error? Because if I integrate the third order Legendre polynomial I get zero for the limit $[-1,1],$ but $C$ cannot be zero. I believe the actual error is given by $Ch^6 f^{(6)}(x)$ where $x$ is a point in the interval of integration. This is a very introductory course so we ignore $f^{(6)}(x)$ (assuming it does not change significantly when the step size is changed).

Comment: Integrate $\left(P_3(x)\right)^2$. That's right, squared! In general it's not possible to work out $C$ and $N$. As I said, $N=6$ seems to be good enough in this case.

Comment: The definite integral gives $C=2/7,$ which corresponds to $N=37.7358\approx 38.$ Yes, but for some reason $N=6$ seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

> > % gaussq
> >
> > function y = gaussq(func, a, b, n);
> >
> > h = (b-a)/n;
> >
> > y = 0;
> >
> > j=(((a+b)/2)-sqrt(3/5)*((b-a)/2));
> >
> > k=((a+b)/2);
> >
> > l=(((a+b)/2)+sqrt(3/5)*((b-a)/2));
> >
> > t=((b-a)/18)*(5*feval(func,j) +  8*feval(func,k) + 5*feval(func,l))
> >
> > for i = 1:n;
> >
> > end